# Multiple InitializeComponent for a winform

Tags: c#, winforms, initializecomponent

We have a highly compact winform with over 180 controls placed in it .
Most of these controls are dynamically placed , some are displayed /hidden based on some preferences.
As a part of optimizing the code i have decided to split the InitializeComponent into three , and in the constructor of the form based on a parameter i will choose the right InitializeComponent which will have only controls wrt to that workflow initalized.

Is this approach right , is there any other way of doing this

Comment: No, that is not a correct approach.  Makes no sense at all to "optimize" InitializeComponent(), you did not write this method yourself.  At best, you'll no longer be able to open the form in the designer anymore, at worst all of the changes you made will disappear without a trace.  A much more logical approach is to create three UserControls.  The form class will now get very small, it only needs to create the UC you want to display.  If these UCs have things in common, likely the case, then derive one from another so you don't duplicate code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion 
I have tired it with a sample form and i was able to open the designer form , The other point With UC do i need to rearrange the controls as per the form design , if so this wont be possible as all the controls are placed dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Seems right to me, assuming you've given up the designer and write the InitializeComponent() methods yourself. Otherwise the designer might overwrite your code in some way.

Comment: any other better implementation you would suggest

Comment: @HansPassant's solution is also good. I haven't done winforms in a while.